# Android application out of memory error when changing Activity

Tags: java, android, image, memory, memory-leaks

my name is John, I am developing this application where I have 2 types of user, each type has 2 menu style view.

What happens It`s that sometimes the application crashes. The LogCat displays "Out of memory on a 11612176-byte allocation".

Here is a portion of the code where I switch between activities:

```
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
    getApplicationContext(), R.array.array_teste,
    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int pos, long id) {


            if (parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString().equals("Formador")) {
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        FormadorActivity.class);
                finish();
                startActivity(i);
            }
            //
        }

        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        }
    });
```

I am almost sure I`m doing something wrong with the images I am using. 
I hope some of you guys can give me a little help I am trying to fix this all the week long.

Thank you for you attention!

UPDATED----

The device I am testing is a Galaxy SII GT-I9100

Here is the LogCat :

```
01-10 16:03:36.243: W/ResourceType(5624): Failure getting entry for 0x010802c0 (t=7 e=704) in package 0 (error -75)
01-10 16:03:37.098: D/dalvikvm(5624): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 5069K, 45% free 21876K/39175K, paused 32ms, total 32ms
01-10 16:03:37.098: D/AbsListView(5624): [unregisterDoubleTapMotionListener]
01-10 16:03:37.103: I/dalvikvm-heap(5624): Grow heap (frag case) to 26.900MB for 5160976-byte allocation
01-10 16:03:37.153: D/dalvikvm(5624): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2K, 32% free 26914K/39175K, paused 48ms, total 48ms
01-10 16:03:37.168: I/MotionRecognitionManager(5624):   .unregisterListener : / listener count = 0->0, ubvf 9budiwrd5ordgfl5BakTrklMrfo$,@,*8b-:)(
01-10 16:03:37.213: D/dalvikvm(5624): GC_CONCURRENT freed 67K, 32% free 26848K/39175K, paused 12ms+4ms, total 60ms
01-10 16:03:37.498: D/dalvikvm(5624): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 112K, 32% free 26735K/39175K, paused 22ms, total 22ms
01-10 16:03:37.498: I/dalvikvm-heap(5624): Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 11612176-byte allocation
01-10 16:03:37.538: D/dalvikvm(5624): GC_BEFORE_OOM freed 0K, 32% free 26735K/39175K, paused 38ms, total 38ms
01-10 16:03:37.538: E/dalvikvm-heap(5624): Out of memory on a 11612176-byte allocation.
01-10 16:03:37.538: I/dalvikvm(5624): "main" prio=5 tid=1 RUNNABLE
01-10 16:03:37.538: I/dalvikvm(5624):   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x40d4d508 self=0x40d3c5a8
01-10 16:03:37.538: I/dalvikvm(5624):   | sysTid=5624 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1075482416
01-10 16:03:37.538: I/dalvikvm(5624):   | schedstat=( 9495706032 3145201445 10530 ) utm=821 stm=128 core=1
01-10 16:03:37.538: I/dalvikvm(5624):   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
01-10 16:03:37.548: I/dalvikvm(5624):   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:625)
01-10 16:03:37.548: I/dalvikvm(5624):   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:478)
01-10 16:03:37.548: I/dalvikvm(5624):   at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:781)
01-10 16:03:37.548: I/dalvikvm(5624):   at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1963)
01-10 16:03:37.548: I/dalvikvm(5624):   at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
01-10 16:03:37.558: I/dalvikvm(5624):   at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:120)
01-10 16:03:37.558: I/dalvikvm(5624):   at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:110)
01-10 16:03:37.558: I/dalvikvm(5624):   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
01-10 16:03:37.558: I/dalvikvm(5624):   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
01-10 16:03:37.563: I/dalvikvm(5624):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:587)
01-10 16:03:37.563: I/dalvikvm(5624):   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
01-10 16:03:37.563: I/dalvikvm(5624):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:660)
01-10 16:03:37.563: I/dalvikvm(5624):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685)
01-10 16:03:37.563: I/dalvikvm(5624):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
01-10 16:03:37.563: I/dalvikvm(5624):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749)
01-10 16:03:37.563: I/dalvikvm(5624):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749)
01-10 16:03:37.563: I/dalvikvm(5624):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
01-10 16:03:37.563: I/dalvikvm(5624):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
01-10 16:03:37.568: I/dalvikvm(5624):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
01-10 16:03:37.568: I/dalvikvm(5624):   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:313)
01-10 16:03:37.568: I/dalvikvm(5624):   at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1924)
01-10 16:03:37.573: I/dalvikvm(5624):   at com.anfengde.ui.call.FormadorActivity.onCreate(FormadorActivity.java:62)
01-10 16:03:37.573: I/dalvikvm(5624):   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5206)
01-10 16:03:37.573: I/dalvikvm(5624):   at  android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
01-10 16:03:37.573: I/dalvikvm(5624):   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2074)
01-10 16:03:37.573: I/dalvikvm(5624):   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2135)
01-10 16:03:37.573: I/dalvikvm(5624):   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:140)
01-10 16:03:37.573: I/dalvikvm(5624):   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1237)
01-10 16:03:37.573: I/dalvikvm(5624):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-10 16:03:37.573: I/dalvikvm(5624):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-10 16:03:37.573: I/dalvikvm(5624):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921)
01-10 16:03:37.573: I/dalvikvm(5624):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-10 16:03:37.573: I/dalvikvm(5624):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-10 16:03:37.573: I/dalvikvm(5624):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
01-10 16:03:37.573: I/dalvikvm(5624):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
01-10 16:03:37.573: I/dalvikvm(5624):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-10 16:03:37.578: A/libc(5624): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000000 (code=1), thread 5624 (nfengde.ui.call)"
```

UPDATED-------------------------

Here is the code I think that could be the cause of the error:

I do this on Both activities on onCreate() and on the onRestart()

```
settings = getSharedPreferences("MyPreferenceFile", 0);
if (settings.getString("estantePadrao", "teste").equals("Claro")) {
    id = getResources().getIdentifier("estante_cursista_v01",
        "drawable", getPackageName());
    imagemPrateleira.setImageResource(id);
} else {
    if (settings.getString("estantePadrao", "teste").equals("Escuro")) {
        id = getResources().getIdentifier("estante_cursista_v02",
            "drawable", getPackageName());
        imagemPrateleira.setImageResource(id);
    } else {
        id = getResources().getIdentifier("estante_cursista_v03",
            "drawable", getPackageName());
        imagemPrateleira.setImageResource(id);
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Which line gets the exception? What are the dimensions of the image? The uncompressed size is 11.6 MB which sounds quite large for the display on a hand held device.  How much memory does the device have?

Comment: Are you trying to load lot of images in that activity? It would be great, if you can explain little more... Paste the whole logcat information, that will also help us to identify the issue

Comment: Thanks for your attention, I`ve updated the post with the Device and the LogCat. Hope you can give me some help. Sorry about the bad identation.

Comment: Are you keeping references to loaded images somewhere, perhaps indirectly in a map, array, or other data structure?

Comment: No, I am just making reference to them at the layout files and at the Activities classes I use "findViewByID()".

Comment: @TedHopp Why? Do i have to create a structure for the images I`m using on the application? Thank you so much for the help.

Comment: Just the opposite. If you are keeping references to images, then they are not subject to garbage collection and you can easily run out of memory. The code you posted doesn't look to me like it would cause the problem you're reporting, so I was speculating what else might be causing it.

Comment: I`ve been searching for a solution it`s been a while and I can`t see what is causing this memory issue. I have even tryied to use "low resolution" images, it takes a little while but at some point the application crashes. Every time when I`m going to open a new activity I call "finish()" to make sure the activity ends and start the new one.

Comment: Another thought -- do you declare a Handler in your activity?

Comment: Yes, I do declare a "handler = new Handler()" on almost every Activity, why?

Comment: Are you subclassing `Handler`? That is, are you doing something like `handler = new Handler() { ... }`? If so, that can cause your activities to leak.

Comment: @TedHopp Hey, I have deleted all the Handlers and still crashes. I have updated the code with what I think it is causing the problem. Could you tell me if is there anything wrong with that code? Thank you!

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with that. I'm guessing that you are leaking your activity objects somewhere. Read through the article [_Avoiding memory leaks_](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/01/avoiding-memory-leaks.html) and make sure you have addressed all the issues discussed there.

Comment: You have the exact line: FormadorActivity.java:62.  Why not start from there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered that the ROM I have installed in my Phone has a memory leak wich was causing the application to crash.

I have tested on other devices and it is working normally.

Thanks for all the help and support!